# Adding Spring bean asynchronously

Tags: spring, grails, asynchronous, vert.x

In my Grails 3.1.14 I app need to add a bean, created in a callback of the asynchronous method call:

```
Vertx.clusteredVertx( [:] ){ AsyncResult<Vertx> res ->
  if( res.succeeded() ){
    Vertx vertx = res.result() // << this should be injected into the appContext
  } 
}
```

so that the instance can be autowired into other artefacts across the whole application.

What's the proper way to achieve this?

Shall I do it with `StaticApplicationContext` or would it break anything?

Another way would be to use a "container-bean" and set it's propery upon completion of the async method, but it's kind of ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper bean that configures its properties based on application context events, using `InitializingBean` interface.

```
class VertxWrapper implements InitializingBean {

   Vertx vertx

   void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
       Vertx.clusteredVertx( [:] ){ AsyncResult<Vertx> res ->
           this.vertx = res.result() // << this should be injected into 
       }   
     }
   }
}
```

And then simply access `vertxWrapper.vertx` from any bean that has `vertxWrapper` injected into it.